# Why is this statement guaranteed to be true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let the set consists of the natural numbers $ \mathbb{N} \in \{1,2,3...\}$. Why is the following statement guaranteed to be true? $∀k∀m∃n((k < n) → (k ≥ m))$. Doesn't this implicitly ask if it is possible to find a $n$ such that $m \leq k < n$? If so, shouldn't be impossible when this is $\forall k$ and $\forall m$?

Comment: Take $n=k$. Then the implication holds because $k<n$ is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the claim asks whether it is always possible to find an $n$ such that *if* this $n$ is larger than $k$, *then* $k\ge m$.

If you can find any $n$ that is *not* larger than $k$, then this is true automatically, no matter what the relation between $k$ and $m$ is.

This implies that you can always make $(k<n)\to(k\ge m)$ true simply by choosing $n$ to be the same as $k$. Or, for that matter, by choosing $n=1$ no matter what $k$ and $m$ are.

Answer (score 1):

The only "difficult" case is when $k < m$, in which case $(k \ge m)$ is *false*.

In order to make the conditional *true*, we have to find a suitable $n$ such that also $(k < n)$ is *false*, and this is always possible : for any $k \in \mathbb N$ we can always find an $n$ such that :

> $k \ge n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k$ and $m$ be natural numbers. If $k\geq m$, then you can take any $n$ since the right part of the implication is true.

If $k<m$ then you have to find a $n$ such that $k<n$ is false you can pick $n=k$ for example.

So for all $k$ and $m$ you there exists $n$ satisfying your property (In fact $n=k$ always satisfy the property ...).